# Unable to Install TestNG in Eclipse luna and Mars version

Tags: testng, testng-eclipse

[image]

unable to install TestNG in latest eclipse version

Comment: i have tried to install  TestNG through "install new software option " click ADD -TestNG ,http://beust.com/eclipse/  it get failed. then try to install via eclipse market place -Following solution are not available message displayed

Comment: i recently downloaded eclipse mars and installed testng from market place. no issues for me.

Answer (score 3):

According to the error message, there is missing M2E (Maven to Eclipse) plugins (or, version not satisfy the minimum required version 1.5) in your Juno package.

Since the 'TestNG M2E Integration' plugin is optional, you can

1. either, install 'TestNG' plugin only, without 'TestNG M2E Integration' plugin
2. or, install the required M2E plugin in your Juno, if you want be benefit from the m2e and testng m2e integration plugins
3. , or, if it's possible, install the latest Eclipse Mars.2 Java EE bundle.

You can track a similar issue here: https://github.com/cbeust/testng/issues/1060

Answer (score 1):

was facing same issue as i was unable to install same from market and install option.
Finally it helped me to sole the issue by following  3rd method listed in below link.

https://www.techbeamers.com/install-testng-in-eclipse-ide/#method3

Install TestNG In Eclipse IDE Via Offline Jar Files.

**First step:**

Firstly download the latest TestNG Jar files from the link given below. We’ve provided the direct URL to download the TestNG version 6.11.

Clicking on the link will download the “site_assembly.zip” file for the TestNG version 6.11. This file contains two folders named as “features” and “plugins“.

The features folder contains the following two files.

org.testng.eclipse.maven.feature_6.11.0.201703011520.jar
org.testng.eclipse_6.11.0.201703011520.jar
The plugins folder contains these two files.

org.testng.eclipse.maven_6.11.0.201703011520.jar
org.testng.eclipse_6.11.0.201703011520.jar
Note – You can check for more recent releases of TestNG

**Second step:**

1. Go to the eclipse installation directory and look for the “dropins”
   folder there.
2. Create a folder inside the dropins folder and name it as
   “testng-eclipse-6.11“.

6->Major version & 11->Minor version of the TestNG plugin.

3. Extract the “site_assembly.zip” file and copy its content i.e. the
   “features” and “plugins” folders to the newly created
   “testng-eclipse-6.11” directory.

The eclipse install directory would now look like this or similar to this.

C:\Users\techbeamers\eclipse
  jee-neon\
     dropins\
        testng-eclipse-6.11\
            features\
               org.testng.eclipse.maven.feature_6.11.0.201703011520.jar
               org.testng.eclipse_6.11.0.201703011520.jar 
            plugins\
               org.testng.eclipse.maven_6.11.0.201703011520.jar
               org.testng.eclipse_6.11.0.201703011520.jar

Note – We’ve tested this option with the Eclipse Neon/juno version.

**Third step:**

Last but not the least, you will need to restart or start the Eclipse to see the TestNG plugin getting loaded into the IDE. However, the process would be slightly slow as the Eclipse will first time load the new plugin.

From Eclipse, by pressing CTRL+N, you can open the “New” wizard. It will load the list of all available module/project templates. By scrolling down in the list, you can make sure that it has the “TestNG” option.